# What If I Put All Nodes of LinkedList into an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, linked-list, nodes

So lately I've been learning C++, and I am studying Linkedlist now.

I am wondering why don't we create Nodes with an array, let's say:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data = 0; //data
    Node* next = nullptr; //next node in the linked list;
};


void deallocateLinkedList(Node* n)
{
 if (n == nullptr) // An empty list; nothing to delete
  return;
 else{
  deallocateLinkedList(n->next);
  delete n;
  n = nullptr;
 }

}

int main()
{

 int k;
 cout<<"enter k as number of nodes"<<endl;
 cin>>k;

 Node* n = new Node [k];                //creates dynamic array;
 for(int i =0;i<k;i++)
 {
  if (i==k-1)
  {
   n[i].data=i;
   n[i].next=nullptr;
  }
  else
  {
   n[i].data=i;
   n[i].next = &n[i+1];
  }
 }
 deallocateLinkedList(n);               //pointer points to the first node;

 cout<<"programmed finished"<<endl;     //indicates successful running


 return 0;
}
```

In this case, the Nodes are linked and also put into an array;

However, the deallocate programme doesn't run completely and exit without error

Is there any problem with this style of creating Linked List or just the deallocation problem?

Comment: You can't add more than `k` nodes this way. If you do, you need to make a new dynamic memory request, copy all of your nodes into that new memory block, deallocate the original block, and then add the new node. This takes time. Also, since each "next" node is just at the next memory address, you can just omit the "next" address. You *know* where the next one is. Congratulations! You just created a vector! It has the benefit of spatial locality (prevents cache thrashing), but needs to be reallocated every once in awhile when you run out of capacity.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad to be an answerable question.  I could pedantically answer it and say "yes there is a problem", in a scenario of my own creation that merely serves to highlight the differences between arrays and linked lists.  Imagine there is someone just like you studying arrays asking "why don't we allocate all nodes and put them in a linked list?"  Dynamic memory allocation is really just deciding which virtual addresses can be used for what purpose.  There are all kinds of schemes for doing so with a laundry list of pros and cods for each.

Comment: Well, it looks like the problems are, as Wyck said, broad and may appear in some certain scenario. And, in this case, the code stoped at "delete n;" inside deallocate function, and I can't figure out the reason for it.

Comment: There are cases where you do want a fixed-size list of nodes (keeps memory fragmentation down, for example), but you have to keep an eye on the book-keeping because you probably won't be allocating more if you run out.

Answer (score 0):

> What If I Put All Nodes of LinkedList into an Array?

Then that's where the nodes are.

> However, the deallocate programme doesn't run completely and exit without error
>
> Is there any problem with this

Yes, there is a problem.

The problem is that you may only pass a pointer to `delete` if you got the pointer from `new` (and it must be deleted at most once, and if you created an array, then you must use `delete[]`).

When you do `delete n;`, you'll find that you never assigned any of `n->next` (which will be the `n` in the recursive call) to have a pointer value that was returned from `new`. As a consequence, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

If you allocate objects like this:

```
Node* n = new Node [k];
```

then you must deallocate like this:

```
delete[] n;
```

Comment: Great! Thx, this works! Looks like I didn't completely understand the "delete"